# What is the time complexity of my codes: reversing words in a string? Should I account for asymmetrical spacing?

Tags: c, string, time-complexity, reverse

**Problem Statement**: Write a function of the declaration `void str_words_in_rev(char *input, int length)` that reverses the words in a string of word/(s). I've implemented two different solutions for it, one of which is extremely complicated.

**Solution 1:** I reverse the entire string using `void reverse(char* string, int start, int end)` function which takes the index of the first and last letter of the string or substring you want to reverse. After that, I reverse *each word* in the string using the same reverse function.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void swapChar(char *a, char *b) {
  char temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

int length(char *string) {
  if(string == NULL)
     return -1;
  int i=0;
  for(;string[i++];);
  return i;
}

void reverse(char* string, int start, int end) {
  int mid = start + (end - start + 1)/2;
  for(int i=start,j=end;i<mid;)
    swapChar(&string[i++], &string[j--]);
}

int main() {
  char str[] = "abc def ghij klmn";
  int i=0, j=0, len = length(str), flag = 0;

  if(str == NULL || !(*str))
     return 0;
  for(;str[j]!='\0';++j) {
     if(str[j] == ' ') {
       flag = 1;
       reverse(str,i,j-1);
       i = j+1;
     }
  }
  if(flag == 1) {
  reverse(str, i, j-1);
  reverse(str,0,len-2);
  }
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

**Solution 2:** I shift every word and following space character (after rearranging it) towards the end by using the pushToEnd function and *then shift the end before the end word which was pushed*. There are printf statements which can be commented out to really understand what's happening, if my explanation is inadequate (which I apologise for).

```
        int pushToEnd(char *str, int length) {

        int len = 0;
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, n = 0;
        for (i = 0; str[i++] != ' ' && i <= length;)
            ++len;
        if (len == length)
            return len;
        //printf("Length of first word:");
        //printf("%d\n", len);
        for (j = i - 1; j>0; --j)
            swapChar(&str[j], &str[j - 1]);
        ++len;
        //printf("After rearranging first word:");
        //printf("%s\n", str);
        //printf("Pushing first word toward the end\n");
        for (; k + 2 * len <= length; k = k + len) {
            for (int l = k; l<k + len; ++l) {
                swapChar(&str[l], &str[l + len]);
            }
            //printf("---%s---\n", str);
        }
        //printf("As blocks:");
        //printf("%s\n", str);
        //printf("K VALUE: %d\n", k);
        for (; k + len<length; ++k) {
            for (n = k + len; n>k; --n) {
                //printf("N VALUE: %d\n", n);
                swapChar(&str[n], &str[n - 1]);
            }
        }
        //printf("One by one:");
        //printf("%s\n", str);
        return len;
    }

    void str_words_in_rev1(char *input, int length){
    int len = 0;
    for (int end = length; end>0; end = end - len) {
        //printf("End:%d\n", end);
        len = pushToEnd(input, end);
    }
}
```

Once you've understood the problem statement and the solutions I've implemented, here are my questions:

what is the time complexity of my solutions? I think the first solution has O(n) complexity and the second one is probably O(n^2) but I'm not sure.

Neither solutions account for asymmetrical spacing. The words are reversed and spacing is reversed as well. It's imperceptible in cases where there is symmetrical spacing/multi-symmetrical spacing. The problem statement was unclear on this, but I'd like your views on whether it should be accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

Solution1 is **O(N)** time complexity. where as,
Solution2 is **O(kN)** where k is the number of words in the string, in the worst case all the words single characters **O(N^2)**. and you are moving word by word towards the end and swapping other words towards the front, so it is **O(kN).**